# Port redirection to gateway on a Mac

Tags: mac, vpn, port, redirection, gateway

How can I redirect certain ports to a specific gateway on Mac OS X Lion?

In my case, exclude torrent traffic from being sent to a VPN tunnel. Meaning that traffic in and out to ports 49152-65534 would use the default gateway. I've heard this is possible with iptables, how about Mac? Are there any other solutions to excluding VPN traffic?